# gwan v7.12.2- files in www folder can't be visited when with query string

Tags: http, g-wan

for example:

```
http://123.456.789.123/page.html, 200 OK  
http://123.456.789.123/page.html?, 404 not found.  
http://123.456.789.123/page.html?debug, 404 not found, too.
```

Answer (score 0):

Our website, using the same version, does not show this behavior:

```
http://www.gwan.ch/en_timeline.html?
http://www.gwan.ch/developers?
```

Both request have the same effect as:

```
http://www.gwan.ch/en_timeline.html
http://www.gwan.ch/developers
```

The support of the query string for static contents (as opposed to servlets) has been implemented in year 2013.